# submitted item user need to get email receipt in sharepoint list 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, development, powershell

Suppose when user submitted item in SharePoint list, he\she need to get email confirmation as your item submitted and sent request to IT Desk as message. And also in a list we have one column name as "Item owner". So based on Item owner, workflow need to pick user(Item owner) and sent email to him\here also with item details(data of all columns). IS it possible to SharePoint workflow using SP designer. Please suggest and thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the workflow and start it automatically when an item is created.

Send the e-mail to user who created the item:

[image]

Send the e-mail to list owner, you need to manually add the column information in the email body:

[image]
[image]